# Supermarket Product Data

Tags: data-request, food

We are looking for super market product data that includes:

- Food products
- Ingredients
- Nutritional values
- Price

Any suggestions on how to find this information? I'm a non-tech person and have found this a big challenge!

Answer (score 4):

USDA maintains a list of commonly eaten foods in the united states including branded items. - https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search [image]

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a multi-faceted solution. The grocery industry is very competitive, with operating margins around [1 to 2 percent.](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/profit-margin-supermarket-17711.html) You are going to need to learn how to tie / relate the databases together. I have a United States of America based solution.

- Food products: [Supermarket API](http://supermarketapi.com/Default.aspx) will provide you with a API to identify products within a number of grocery stores, it is free for a 3-week trial
- Ingredients: [Open Food Facts](http://openfoodfacts.org/)
- Nutritional Values: [The USDA National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference](https://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=8964) provides nutritional information
- Price: The aforementioned Supermarket API will allow you access to the price, but for $1,299 per year. This is not an open data solution, but prices amongst grocers is very competitive.